# Pop Up form - Positioning and Styling

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-ui

So I have this Pop up form which works fine but it doesn't let me control where it pops up even when I try to apply CSS it doesn't work.Also the form should be in the `<aside>` form but it is not showing there.

I have the follow code for the html

```
    <aside>
        <form method="post" class="basic-frm" id="newFolder">
            <label>
                <h1>New Folder</h1>
            </label>
            <label>
                <span>Title:</span>
                <input id="title" type="text" name="title"/>
            </label>
            <label>
                <span>Description</span>
                <input id="description" type="text" name="description"/>
            </label>
            <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="button"/>
            <input id="cancel" type="button" name="cancle" value="Cancel" class="button"/>

        </form>

        <h1>Welcome</h1>
        <img src="images/newFolder.svg" onmouseover="this.src='images/newFolderHover.svg'" onmouseout="this.src='images/newFolder.svg'" id="clicky">
        <p>New folder</p>
    </aside>
```

Jquery code is the following :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#newFolder').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 600
    });
    $('#clicky').button().click(function() {
        $('#newFolder').dialog("open")
    });
    $('#cancel').button().click(function() {
        $('#newFolder').dialog("close")
    });
});
```

CSS like colors and stuff work but not the width for example but not the margin what so ever, I also want it to stay in the `<aside>` which it is not.

Comment: this has got nothing to do with 'PHP'

Comment: hey man, just dont get it too complicated http://jsfiddle.net/6J5dX/

Answer (score 1):

You should also specify the `position`:

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({ 
    position: { my: "left top", at: "left bottom", of: "aside" } 
});
```

This will let you position the dialog relative to another element ('aside' selector).

Check the [jQuery UI Dialog API](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-position).

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that in your css you have some code that defines the style of your "aside" tag..

in your css add some coordinates for your tag as valign: top bottom... align: left,center,... an so on

and in your code of html

```
<aside>
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
        <img src="images/newFolder.svg" onmouseover="this.src='images/newFolderHover.svg'"   onmouseout="this.src='images/newFolder.svg'" id="clicky">
        <p>New folder</p>

        <form method="post" class="basic-frm" id="newFolder">
            <label>
                <h1>New Folder</h1>
            </label>
            <label>
                <span>Title:</span>
                <input id="title" type="text" name="title"/>
            </label>
            <label>
                <span>Description</span>
                <input id="description" type="text" name="description"/>
            </label>
            <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="button"/>
            <input id="cancel" type="button" name="cancle" value="Cancel" class="button"/>

        </form>


    </aside>
```

the welcome part  fomr me should be on top, isn't it??